# Wrapping "paths" around plot boundaries in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

So I'm trying to plot the trace of some particles moving on a 2D surface. 
I have programmed them so they wrap around the boundaries when I calculate the data, but when I plot the data, the line goes across the surface instead through the boundaries.

[image]

You can see on the attached picture, that the lines goes across the surface, even though the particle went up through the top. 
Any ideas on how this could be done, if possible?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want as the end result. Can you put some code up? The plot diagram appears to show lines directly connecting each point as they get plotted (tracing them), what do you actually expect to happen? I'm not understanding what you mean by the boundaries. The boundaries made by the lines or the  boundaries of the graph or something else?

Comment: My code is quite messy, and wont really make it clearer. I want the line to go through the top border and come up through the bottom. 
Imagine the particles moving on a closed surface, eg. the surface of a sphere.

Comment: Ahh I think I understand what you mean (I think). Kind of how the old Snake games on Nokia could be boundary-less. I don't know how you could trace this without connecting the points. You could start a new trace when it crosses the boundaries? Then you could differentiate them with a different colour and remember which colours you have used in order. To show continuity will be hard on a flat surface if it wraps around.

Comment: Exactly like the old Snake game. I was hoping that matplotlib had a function that would automatically do this for me. I might try your suggestion if can't find such a function, thanks!